# Javascript onclick proxy

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I want to proxy `onclick` event

Here is what I tried:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.onclick = new Proxy(HTMLElement.prototype.onclick, {
  set: (target, thisArgs, argsList) => {
    console.log(thisArgs)
    return target.apply(thisArgs, argsList)
  }
}
```

using `apply:` trap, I could use the above code to proxy `getElementById`. But when I try to proxy `onclick` I get `Illegal invocation` error. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLElement.prototype.onclick` is a getter/setter. When you reference

```
HTMLElement.prototype.onclick
```

you invoke the getter, with a calling context of `HTMLElement.prototype` - but the getter expects a calling context of an *actual element*, so it throws.

You could use `Object.defineProperty` instead - and there doesn't look to be any need for the proxy, just intercept the call:

```js
const { get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onclick');
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onclick', {
  set: function(newHandler) {
    console.log(newHandler)
    return set.call(this, newHandler)
  },
  get
});

document.body.onclick = () => console.log('foo');
```

```html
click
```